# Compressed GZIP Request sent to jetty using jersey-client is not working for FormDataMultiPart

Tags: jetty, multipartform-data, embedded-jetty, jersey-client

Jersey Client code and jetty.xml -
...

```
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws FileNotFoundException
    {   
        String token = "abc";
        String file = "C:\\importedcerts\\TestpkgRoll.log";
        String uri = "http://localhost:8008/api/arsys/v1/entry/myattach1";
        
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
        
        .register(EncodingFilter.class)
        .register(GZipEncoder.class)
        .property(ClientProperties.USE_ENCODING, "gzip")
        .register(MultiPartFeature.class).build();

        FormDataMultiPart formDataMultiPart = new FormDataMultiPart();
        // json data
        String json = "{ \"values\" : { ";
        json += "\"Submitter__c\" : \"Allen\", ";
        json += "\"Short Description__c\" : \"testing 123\""
                + ", ";
        json += "\"Attachment__c\" : \"testrollback.log\"";
        json += " } }";

        
        formDataMultiPart.field("entry", json,
                MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
            StreamDataBodyPart streamDataBodyPart = new StreamDataBodyPart("attach-Attachment__c", new FileInputStream(new File(file)), "testrollback.log", MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE);
            formDataMultiPart.bodyPart(streamDataBodyPart);

        Builder request = client.target(uri).request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        request.header("Authorization", "AR-JWT " + token);
        request.header("Content-Encoding", "gzip");

        Response response = null;
        response = request.method("POST",
//                Entity.json(json));
                Entity.entity(formDataMultiPart, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE));
        System.out.println(response);

    }
}

<Call name="insertHandler">
    <Arg>
      <New id="GzipHandler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler">
        <Set name="minGzipSize"><Property name="jetty.gzip.minGzipSize" deprecated="gzip.minGzipSize" default="0"/></Set>
        <Set name="checkGzExists"><Property name="jetty.gzip.checkGzExists" deprecated="gzip.checkGzExists" default="false"/></Set>
        <Set name="inflateBufferSize"><Property name="jetty.gzip.inflateBufferSize" default="1024"/></Set>

        <Set name="excludedAgentPatterns">
          <Array type="String">
            <Item><Property name="jetty.gzip.excludedUserAgent" deprecated="gzip.excludedUserAgent" default=".*MSIE.6\.0.*"/></Item>
          </Array>
        </Set>

        <Call name="addIncludedMimeTypes">
          <Arg><Array type="String">
            <Item>application/octet-stream</Item>
          </Array></Arg>
        </Call>
        
        <Call name="addExcludedMimeTypes">
          <Arg><Array type="String">
            <Item>application/json</Item>
          </Array></Arg>
        </Call>
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </Call>
```

...

However above request processing fails with Exception -
org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEParsingException: Missing start boundary

However in my client when I comment out as below
...

```
//        .register(EncodingFilter.class)
//        .register(GZipEncoder.class)
//        .property(ClientProperties.USE_ENCODING, "gzip")

//        request.header("Content-Encoding", "aplication/gzip, gzip");
```

...
I am able to process request successfully , what could be an issue when above portion is uncommented , is it in client code or jetty.xml which resides on server ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to enable the `GzipHandler` on Jetty to have it process compressed content (request or response).

That XML block you pasted (from the `gzip` module on jetty-home) is not something you should be editing to enable `GzipHandler`, use the proper split of `${jetty.home}` and `${jetty.base}`, enable the `gzip` module,  and then configure it with the appropriate properties that this split provides for you.

By default, the auto-decompression of request body content is disabled.

But setting `GzipHandler.setInflateBufferSize(int)` to a positive value the decompression (aka inflation) of request body content will occur.

Comment: Finally found this helpful attribute for auto-decompression of request body! This link also helped me to set it up in jetty.xml, https://github.com/jetty/jetty.project/blob/jetty-10.0.x/jetty-server/src/main/config/etc/jetty.xml