# How to enable gzip compression for requests in spring boot rest service

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, compression, gzip

We have a spring boot REST application in which we have the following configuraion,

> server.compression.enabled=true
> server.compression.mime-types=text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/javascript,application/javascript,application/json
> server.compression.min-response-size=1024

But I believe this compresses only the response. Does it handle compressed request too?
If not, is there a way in which we can de-compress the compressed request?

We are using jetty server with spring boot

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66622205/compressed-gzip-request-sent-to-jetty-using-jersey-client-is-not-working-for-for, you can probably use a Jetty Customizer from Spring Boot to enable it.